# Is LiveData cached in ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I need some clarification on how LiveData works with Android's Architecture components like Room.

Let's say I use this way of getting live data:

```
Dao:
@Query("SELECT * FROM check_table")
LiveData<List<DataItem>> getAllItems();

Repository Constructor:
private DataRepository(Application application) {
       DataDatabase database = DataDatabase.getInstance(application);
       dataDao = database.dataDao();
       dataItems = dataDao.getAllData();
   }

ViewModel Constructor:
public DataViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = DataRepository.getInstance(application);
        dataItems = repository.getDataItems();
    }

Getter:
public LiveData<List<DataItem>> getDataItems() {
        return dataItems;
    }
```

Is the LiveData in ViewModel being updated everytime even when there are no active listeners?

I'm asking because I want to use the same data in pretty much all my fragments, and I want to know if the data has to be queried every time I add the listener to the data in one of my fragments or the LiveData object is updated in ViewModel and when i switch fragments and add listener to that LiveData in there, it just gets cached LiveData instead of querying for it once again

Comment: `Is the LiveData in ViewModel being updated everytime even when there are no active listeners?` no `when i switch fragments and add listener to that LiveData in there, it just gets cached LiveData instead of querying for it once again` it only gets re-queried if there was an invalidation (write to the observed table), otherwise it gets the cached. In fact, you get the cached AND the re-query after invalidation.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So when there's a period of time with no active listeners, and in that time the data changes, the LiveData isn't updated but it knows that the change has been made, and it will re-query as soon as the observer is added right? Otherwise I don't know how the LiveData would know if it should give me the cached data or re-query in case of fragment change (and observer) in my example.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens.